# xdmp:email filtering out email addresses that don't pass a predicate

Tags: email, xquery, marklogic

Let's say I have a predicate:

```
declare function local:should-send-email($email-address) {
  ... fn:true() ...
  ... fn:false() ...
};
```

And then I have an email element for use with `xdmp:email`:

```
<em:Message
 xmlns:em="URN:ietf:params:email-xml:"
 xmlns:rf="URN:ietf:params:rfc822:">
  <rf:subject>Test</rf:subject>
  <rf:from>
    <em:Address>
      <em:name>Test Name</em:name>
      <em:adrs>test-from@test000.com</em:adrs>
    </em:Address>
  </rf:from>
  <rf:to>
    <em:Address>
      <em:name>Test Name</em:name>
      <em:adrs>test-to-1@test000.com</em:adrs>
    </em:Address>
    <em:Address>
      <em:name>Test Name</em:name>
      <em:adrs>test-to-2@test000.com</em:adrs>
    </em:Address>
  </rf:to>
  <em:content>Hello World</em:content>
</em:Message>
```

Lets say one of the to addresses passes the predicate and one doesn't. What is an efficient way to remove the em:Address element for the one that doesn't pass?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you intend to start with the complete `<em:Message>` element, you can use a recursive typeswitch to filter out the invalid email addresses - the logic is very similar to XSLT:

```
declare function local:filter-addresses(
  $node as node()
) as item()*
{
  typeswitch ($node)
  case element(em:Address) return
    if (not(local:should-send-email($node/em:adrs)))
    then () (: Filter :)
    else $node
  case element() return (: Passthrough :)
    element { node-name($node) } {
      $node/@*,
      for $child in $node/node()
      return local:filter-addresses($child)
    }
  default return $node
};
```

Comment: Works great!

I only changed one minor thing. After:
$node/@*,
I added:
$node/text(),

Thanks for the efficient solution.

Comment: @TutanRamen Ah, I see. A *very slightly* more compact way to do that would be to change `$node/*` to `$node/node()`. This would also have the added benefit of keeping text nodes and other nodes in their original order, which shouldn't be an issue here, but just FYI if you are ever doing something similar with more complex XML. I made the change above for reference.

Comment: Quite the handy little function